# Creating a database table from different directories

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, awk, scripting

So, I want to create a table and insert records in it from .tsv files located in multiple directories. All files are of same columns, same names, same format(.tsv) but have different genetic informations in them and are from different named folders.
Does anyone knows of a simple way to do it? I want  all the information from all those files in one single table.
I'm not a programmer, but do know basic bash and sql. Any ideas are appreciated.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Find a programmer.  You are in over your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about mysqlimport

```
cat ./*/*.tsv > table_name.tsv
mysqlimport \
    -u root \
    -ptmppassword \
    --fields-terminated-by="\t" 
    [other options] \
    db_name \
    table_name.tsv
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html